# Show default selected value of MatSelect inside a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have this FormArray of select fields and I am trying to show the default selected values with no luck. My form looks like this:

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="Form">
           <ng-container formArrayName="taxes" *ngFor="let item of taxes.controls; let i = index">
                <div [formGroupName]="i" >
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select (selectionChange)="setTax($event.value, i)">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let tax of taxesObjects" [value]="tax">
                                {{ tax.rate }}%
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </ng-container> 
        </ng-container>
```

the `taxesObjects` look like this:

```
 taxesObjects: SalesTaxModel[] = [
                {id: "1", name: "tax1", rate: 9},
                {id: "2", name: "tax2", rate: 12},
               ];
```

The select field is not associated with any `FormControl`, I am using the `setTax()` method to update my form:

```
setTax(tax, index) {

        let taxAmount = parseFloat((tax.rate / 100 * this.preTaxValue).toFixed(2));

        this.taxes.at(index).get("amount").setValue(taxAmount)

        this.taxes.at(index).get("sales_tax").setValue(tax)
 }
```

When I use default values for the select fields, I just don't know how to show the selected value on the control. Can anybody help with this?

Here is a blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-71mrvk

Comment: Move away from getters and setters my friend. You're looking for `[(ngModel)]` and `(ngModelChange)`. The ngModel defines the variable you'll use to track the current selection, and ngModelChange performs any calculations needed when the selection changes.

Comment: How am I supposed to use `ngModel` inside a FormArray? I don't quite get this...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using mat-option value as a object **[value]="tax"**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let tax of taxesObjects" [value]="tax">
    {{ tax.rate }}%
</mat-option>
```

Value for the option will be

```
{id: "1", name: "tax1", rate: 9}
```

You must be setting similar object as default value to the select. When you set the default value, it tries to match the set value to each entry in the list (each mat-option) by checking equality and since it's a JSON object object no entry matches unless you do deep check.

To solve this you can use [compareWith](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) for mat-select

```
// Template
<select [compareWith]="compareFn"  [formControl]="selectedCountriesControl">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
        {{country.name}}
    </option>
</select>

// component code
compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```